# Does my schematic look correct? (Double check)

Tags: schematics, kicad, chip-design, circuit-design

I am a complete beginner when it comes to creating schematics and PCBs. I also don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, because I am also pretty new to writing forum entries.

I have drawn following schematic for an STM32103 microprocessor and don't know if I the whole project would work. Could someone have a look at it?

Design claims are:
*The curcit is supposed to be a kind of "replacement" for a Stm32 Discovery board.*

- UART-Connection via PinHeader
- I2C-Connection via Pin-Header
- Debugger Headers for the STM-Link directly on the borad
- In addition, a UART transceiver, which is installed directly via USB

**Schematics** (before Edit)
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Decoupling capacitors on VBUS? R13 and associated 3.3V is drawn upside down.

Comment: "I also don't know if this is the right place to ask this question" Design reviews of schematics is fine and on-topic here.

Comment: No, it would not work. For quite many reasons. It would be difficult to answer as it will require a list of problems, and as each answer may list different problems, it will be difficult to judge the best answer, beicause they all might be correct and they all might list a different problem which prevents the circuit from working. So review questions are difficult. However, it looks like you can fix most of the problems by just looking at datasheet examples. It is unclear why the design is like it is, as it does not follow datasheet examples at all what kind of circuitry chips need to work.

Comment: C1 Needs to be directly on the input of the voltage regulator. And are those really 125R resistors next to it? There are probably other issues as well

Comment: `... don't know if I the whole project would work.` What is the circuit intended for or to do? No explanation/information about the circuit's operation is given.

Comment: Please edit that information into your question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering all the Tips and fixes of the schematic, the new schematic looks like followed.

I change following parts of the design.
**NRST:**

- Deleted 3.3V and Resistor
- added an second ground (see Datasheet)
  [image]

**U5:**

- RS: Deleted the R14 Resistor → cause i don’t want to use slope control or other ways
- CAN_RX: Added an Condensator of 30pF with grounding!

**U3:**

- RST set to high

**VDDA:**

- Changed VBUS → to +3.3VA

**Pull-Resistor:**

- value changes from mostly 1k5 → 4k7
- **changed the value of R3 from 4k7 back to 1k5**

**HSE:**

- HSE_OUT → added an R of 390
- HSE Condensator → value change from 10pF to 20pF
  [image]
  → Choose: HSE external crystal/ceramic resonator (Figure 7)
  [image]

**FINAL SCHEMATIC**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks to all of you guys for the help.

Comment: There is no added value in two series resistors to D5, R3 is a bit high.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for the advice. I changed it back to a value of 1k5 (like I had in the beginning).

Answer (score 5):

Some problems spotted at a glance:

- The power supply looks very naively designed with a LED and resistor in series. That will not work, obviously. The LED and resistor should be towards ground. You can't place series resistors on your supply or they'll muck the whole thing up completely.
- R9 + R2 seems like strange values picked at a whim. For most LED you'd pick a series resistor for approximately 5mA. So if the LED has forward voltage 1V, you'd pick (3.3V - 1V) / 5mA = 460R, roughly. Same value for both LEDs if they have the same forward voltage.
- Why is VBUS connected to 3.3V through a ferrite? Isn't VBUS something like USB 5V? If so are you sure you can connect 5V to a Vref pin on a MCU powered with 3.3V? I'm not making any sense of this.
- U3 reset pin should likely not be left floating or it may reset at a whim. Tie to 3V3.
- R14 is wrong. If you mean to use slope control you'll have to follow the graph in the MCP2551 datasheet, which lists much higher resistances. If you don't intend to use slope control then tie the pin to ground.
- You shouldn't connect a switch directly to a MCU pin unless you are sure about ESD ratings. Double-check what the NRST pin guarantees in terms of ESD contact spikes.
- Your pull resistor values are inconsistent. 1.5k is very low. Industry standard tends to be 4k7 or 10k.
- Don't draw pull-up resistors pointing downwards. When drawing schematics, + is upwards, GND is downwards.

Comment: There's another: Paralleled individual regulators. USB-to-UART chip has an on-chip 3.3V regulator. Its output (VDD - pin6) is tied to net **+3.3V** which is already tied to AMS1117-3.3's output.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, that means i have to delet the +3.3V supply?

Comment: @Y-E-Quit Normally if the CP2102's regulator is enough to supply the whole circuit then you can get rid of the VBUS-to-3V3 regulator (AMS1117). Otherwise, or if you can't be bothered with power consumption calculations, simply remove the 3.3V net connection from CP2102's pin-6 so that it doesn't short to the AMS1117's output.

Comment: @Lundin, got one more question. My Micro-USB-B (connected to PA11 and PA12), can I use this USB to Programm my Microcontroller? Or does it only supply my board with Power?

Comment: @Y-E-Quit You might be able to use it for "bootloader" purposes, check the specific STM32 manual if there's on-chip support for such. However, programming/debugging during development should be carried out over SWD. If you think you can skip SWD, you are doing it wrong. As for production programming that's another story entirely and bootloaders are quite unsuitable. Some companies have it as their main business to deliver pre-flashed MCUs with your firmware already inside, before PCB assembly.